# How to manually send next signal to a observable in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I create an observable using the following code:

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let myJust = { (element: String) -> Observable<String> in
    return Observable.create { observer in
        observer.on(.next(element))
        //observer.on(.completed)
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

That code comes from RxSwift's sample code.

If I create an empty Observable `myJust`, and later I try to send it a value:

```
myJust("").on(.completed)
```

I get the following error:

```
error: value of type 'Observable<String>' has no member 'on'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't. `Observable`s can only be observed. If you want to push values, you'll need a `Subject`. 
A `Subject` is both an `Observable` and an `Observer` so it can emit and listen to Events. 
In RxSwift you can also create a  `Variable` which you can bind an `Observable` to.

Quick example for `BehaviorSubject`:

```
let subject = BehaviorSubject(value: 1)
subject.on(.Next(2))
subject.on(.Next(3))
subject.on(.Completed)
```

Comment: Driver cannot do that also? Only subjects and variable can push values?

Comment: Afaik, it's only subjects and variables :)